# Is it possible to make the current floor start from floor 0?

Tags: python, function, class, while-loop

```
def goDownfloor(current, target):
    for floor in range(current, target, -1):
        current -= 1
        if floor != target+1:
            print(f"current floor is {current}.")
        else:
            print(f"Arrived at the {target} . Goodbye.")
    return current

def goUpfloor(current, target):
    for floor in range(current, target):
        current += 1
        if floor != target-1:
            print(f"current floor is {current}.")
        else:
            print(f"Arrived at the {target} . Goodbye.")
    return current

currentFloor = 1
while(True):
    targetFloor = int(input("Enter the floor you want to go to (enter -100 for outages):"))
    if targetFloor == -100:
        break
    else:
        if targetFloor > currentFloor:
            currentFloor = goUpfloor(currentFloor, targetFloor)
        elif targetFloor < currentFloor:
            currentFloor = goDownfloor(currentFloor, targetFloor)
        elif targetFloor == currentFloor:
            print('Please re-enter another floor.')
```

Could you please keep this Python code the same and re-read it assuming that every building has a lobby floor (floor 0)? And if the result is, for example, pressing the 3rd floor, the current floor should be displayed up to the 3rd floor. Please help me.

I tried changing the current floor to the 0th floor, but it failed because the current floor had to be set to the 1st floor. I tried setting the current floor to 0 above the 'current += 1' part, but it didn't work.

Comment: the counting variable is `-1` so it is counting downwards from `current` to `target`.  So, if current = 0, then target would need to be negative. . .  So, did you mean to ask this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this answers the question but when I set:
`currentFloor = 0`
The code works fine. Is this what you wanted?

Full context:

```
def goDownfloor(current, target):
    for floor in range(current, target, -1):
        current -= 1
        if floor != target+1:
            print(f"current floor is {current}.")
        else:
            print(f"Arrived at the {target} . Goodbye.")
    return current

def goUpfloor(current, target):
    for floor in range(current, target):
        current += 1
        if floor != target-1:
            print(f"current floor is {current}.")
        else:
            print(f"Arrived at the {target} . Goodbye.")
    return current

currentFloor = 0
while(True):
    targetFloor = int(input("Enter the floor you want to go to (enter -100 for outages):"))
    if targetFloor == -100:
        break
    else:
        if targetFloor > currentFloor:
            currentFloor = goUpfloor(currentFloor, targetFloor)
        elif targetFloor < currentFloor:
            currentFloor = goDownfloor(currentFloor, targetFloor)
        elif targetFloor == currentFloor:
            print('Please re-enter another floor.')
```